# Entity Framework Core DbFunction for square root

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm porting my site over from **.NET Framework / MVC 5 / EF6** to **.NET Core 3.1 MVC / EF Core**. MSSQL Server for the database.

EF6 has `SqlFunctions` of which one method is `SquareRoot`, which translates to using `SQRT` in sql queries against MSSQL Server.

EFCore does not have the `SqlFunctions` class. It does have an equivalent `DbFunctions` class but this is missing lots of methods.

After some googling about I've come up with the following for translating the LINQ query to sql:

**MyDbFunctions.cs**

```
public static class MyDbFunctions
{
    public static double? SquareRoot(double? arg) => throw new Exception();
}
```

**OnModelCreating method in DbContext**

```
var sqrtMethodInfo = typeof(MyDbFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(MyDbFunctions.SquareRoot));
modelBuilder
    .HasDbFunction(sqrtMethodInfo)
    .HasTranslation(args => SqlFunctionExpression.Create("SQRT", args, typeof(double?), null));
```

**Usage:**

```
from a in context.Posts
let sqrt = MyDbFunctions.SquareRoot(a.someColumnWithDoubleValue)
where sqrt < 1337
select new MyViewModel
{
   Sqrt = sqrt
    ...
};
```

This seems to work nicely. I can see the use of `SQRT` within the generated query (using SQL Server Profiler) and the where clause being applied. It also looks near identical to what EF6 generates.

I'm wondering if any EF Core pros can see anything wrong/pitfalls with the implementation (or improve on it)?

Comment: would it not be more in vogue to make this an extension method of DBFunctions?

Comment: @suraj How about using `Math.Pow(a.someColumnWithDoubleValue, 0.5)`

Comment: @Ewan - it would, easily changed :) Additionally, I suppose the "pro" way of doing it would be using IMethodCallTranslator.

Comment: @PeterCsala I thought this would cause the expression to be evaluated locally (I'm sure I tried to use a Math function in an older version of EF years ago and this happened). But to my surprise it doesn't! Instead it appears to use POWER within the generated query, very cool. This leads to the question - why? Is POWER faster than SQRT in queries?

Comment: Out of curiosity I've just discovered that even Math.Sqrt is correctly translated to use SQRT in the generated query - so there's not even any need to use this custom function in EF Core.

Comment: @suraj No I don't think so. Simply just not all of the `Math` functions have mapper. [Current translators](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/tree/c9b5916a4e0fff763febea00da793ebd4113632d/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal), [5.0's translators](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/074fd1b7afe4da26850eaafbc38e6fae671fd76c). Related [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7601)

Comment: @PeterCsala seems you're correct, I was not aware of this. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @suraj Would you mind If I summarize the comments into an answer?

Comment: @PeterCsala not at all, anything that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I capture the main essence of the comments.

#### Facts

- As the OP has mentioned the `Sqrt` functionality is no exposed on the `EF.Functions` in EFCore

  - EF 6 exposed it through `SqlFunctions`
- `Math.XYZ` functions can be used in Linq2Entities

  - Not all of the functions have translator to the corresponding SQL function, [current state](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/tree/c9b5916a4e0fff763febea00da793ebd4113632d/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal)
  - As a part of this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7601) more function translators will [in v5](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/074fd1b7afe4da26850eaafbc38e6fae671fd76c)

#### Solutions

- `Math.Pow` can be used as well, like this: `Math.Pow(a.someColumnWithDoubleValue, 0.5)`

  - This will be translated into `POWER`
- `Math.Sqrt` can be used as well, like this: `Math.Pow(a.someColumnWithDoubleValue)`

  - This will be translated into `SQRT`
  - If the data type would be decimal then explicit cast is needed:

    - `Math.Pow((double)a.someColumnWithDecimalValue)`
    - Translated into `SQRT(CONVERT(Float, ...)`